# Jmeter CSS Selector Extractor

Tags: jmeter, css-selectors

In JMeter, I'm trying to extract the values of property key values using CSS selector extractor, for the attached HTML body

I used the expression **#propertySummaryList > div**, but not seeing any response in debug sampler.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor), simpler and faster.

Use parameters:

Left Boundary : `propertykey="`

Right Boundary: `"`

Match No.: `-1`

> Allows the user to extract values from a server response using left and right boundaries

Comment: Thanks @User7294900. I tried this but no match returned. Will try to explore more.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't post [code as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2897748) as it's way harder to reproduce your issue
2. Try out the following selector instead: `div[class=propertySummaryList] > div`

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)
- [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri. I tried the options and had no matches found. I have included the html source, with the value to extract (44772164).
I also tried the expression div[class=SummaryList] > div but with no luck
</div>
<div class="span-18 last" style="margin-bottom:35px>
                        <div id="propertySummaryList" class="summaryList"></div>
                        <div id="soldSummaryList" class="summaryList"></div>
    <div id="summaryListContent" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="summaryListItem   " propertyKey="44772164">